# Were any Popes critics of the Iberian "Blood purity" doctrines?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, conversion

Spain had at one point of its history a significant Jewish population (Sephardi Jews) as well as a large Muslim minority following the conquests of Islamic realms in Iberia. Judaism and Islam were both outlawed in Spain and Portugal, forcing many people to either go into exile or convert to Christianity.

The repression did not end with conversion, as there was considerable legal and social strain directed against people who could not trace a sufficiently Christian ancestry. These people were known as *converso* or *morisco* and were subject to many restrictions evolving over the centuries, including for instance bans from military or public offices. Collectively, the system of repression was known as *Limpieza de sangre*, meaning "purity of blood", and it created a de facto caste system in the Spanish Empire until the system's gradual dismantling in the 19th century.

Doctrines ostracizing converts and especially later progeny of converts seems like it undermines the sacrament of baptism. The Spanish nation is known of its strong bond to the Catholic church, so it would seem natural that a Pope would opine on the issue and have their word taken seriously.

Did any Catholic Pope comment on these "blood purity" doctrines? What was the reception?